# How to monitor EC2 EMR cluster status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I know I can use aws cli api to get the a cluster status, but is there a way that AWS service can send an alert when the cluster is terminated with error? using API will still take time. I am looking for a real time like reporting service from Amazon, is there any?
Thanks

```
aws emr list-clusters --cluster-states TERMINATED
```

I have used this command to get the cluster states but it is not a real time report, I appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: How soon do you need to know that a cluster is terminated?

Comment: at least within 3 mins

Comment: I don't know how cloudwatch can be used for this. One way I can think of is to fire a lambda every minute to check the status of the cluster and send you a notification if the cluster is terminated. You will not pay extra since it will be under free tier. Few lines of code can do this.

Comment: @helloV can you give an example of that, thanks..